# Trying to check for empty value in input

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box that changes another paragraph in my site with JavaScript. It works flawlessly, except for the fact that when I enter nothing in the input, it blanks out the paragraph.

I don't want this to happen. I've tried almost every piece of code I've found online to fix this issue but nothing has worked.

```
<div class="tasklist">
   <p id="task1" style="color:#d3d3a3">You don't have any tasks.</p>
</div><br>
<script>
  const element = document.getElementById("task1");
  var task = document.input["task"].value;
  function getInputValue() {
    let value = document.getElementById("task").value;
    element.innerHTML = (value);
    document.getElementById("task1").style.color = "white";
  }
</script>
Enter a task:<br>
<input type="text" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Pay Bills">
<button onclick="getInputValue();" onclick="changeColor()">+ Add</button>
```

Comment: So what *should* it do if the input is empty?

Comment: Probably throw an alert and don't change anything. It doesn't matter to me though, I'll probably change it later.

Comment: this is because JS and HTML are Top Down programming systems

Comment: Are you saying your problem is that you can't figure out how to tell if `value` is an empty string? I'd love to know what failed attempts you've made to check if this is the case.

Comment: Literally the first result on Google. And the one after that. And the one after that. AND the one after that.

Comment: Please include your attempt(s) and we can help from there!

Comment: "the first result on Google" — after searching for *what* exactly? What was the *exact* search you did? A test as simple as `element.value.trim().length === 0` could tell you if the element is empty or blank.

Comment: @mykaf https://pastebin.com/xNuD3jNc This is the one i've excessively tried. It just makes it so that not only nothing happens when you don't put anything, but nothing happens when you enter any characters either.

Comment: @StephenP Using that returns the same result as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div id="tasklist">
  <p id="msg" style="color:red">You don't have any tasks.</p>
</div>
<br>

<script>
  const element = document.getElementById("msg");
  element.style.display = "none";

  function add() {
    let value = document.getElementById("task").value;

    if (value && value.trim() != "") {
      document.getElementById("task").value = "";
      element.style.display = "none";
      const taskContainer = document.getElementById('tasklist');

      const task = document.createElement('p');
      task.textContent = value;
      taskContainer.append(task)
    } else {
      element.style.display = "block";
    }

  }
</script>
Enter a task:<br>
<input type="text" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Pay Bills">
<button onclick="add();">+ Add</button>
```

Comment: This one works perfectly except for the fact that the part where it appends the div doesn't work as intended - the div doesn't apply for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add value checker - it will prevent from setting innerHTML as "".
Secondly i think You want to add element with another task, not removing older ones.
use .append() to add at the end of parent or prepend() to add at the begginning of parrent.

```
 <div class="tasklist"><p id="task1" style="color:#d3d3a3">You don't have any tasks.</p></div><br>
    <script>
    const element = document.getElementById("task1");
    var task = document.input["task"].value;
    function changeColor(){console.log("color")};
    function getInputValue() {
    let value = document.getElementById("task").value;
    if(value.length>0){
    element.append(
        Object.assign(
            document.createElement("p"),
            {textContent:value}
        )
    );
    document.getElementById("task1").style.color = "white";}}
  </script>
  Enter a task:<br>
  <input type="text" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Pay Bills">
  <button onclick="getInputValue();changeColor()" >+ Add</button>
```

if You rather want to replace Your first child then

```
<div class="tasklist"><p id="task1" style="color:#d3d3a3">You don't have any tasks.</p></div><br>
    <script>
    const element = document.getElementById("task1");
    var task = document.input["task"].value;
    function getInputValue() {
    let value = document.getElementById("task").value;
    if(value.length>0){
    element.replaceChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("p"),{textContent:value}),element.firstChild);
    document.getElementById("task1").style.color = "white";}}
    </script>
  Enter a task:<br>
  <input type="text" id="task" name="task" placeholder="Pay Bills">
  <button onclick="getInputValue()" >+ Add</button>
```

Comment: The only 'falsey' strings are strings with a length of zero, so assuming value can't be null or undefined, `if (value && value.length>0)` is redundant, and `let value = document.getElementById("task").value;` can never produce null or undefined. You could get undefined if you used the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` operator, like `let value = document.getElementById("task")?.value;`

Comment: Yes , exaclty. Thank You . I missed that :)

Comment: So i guess my answer is worth nothing...

Comment: "So i guess my answer is worth nothing" -?- What? I certainly didn't say that in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh! It wasn't to You ! :)  I turned to @asterisk :)